# Странное поведение backdround-size у svg спрайтов в exlorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Я использую `svg` спрайты для иконок.

Вот так выглядит верстка во всех браузерах (хром, опера, мозила):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так выглядит в explorer 11
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
  .menu-two__icon {
    width: 58px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    background: url("../img/svg/principles.svg") no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: auto 200%;
            background-size: auto 200%;
```

Я впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, до этого прекрасно все работало в explorer. Просматриваю старые проекты и не могу понять. Код аналогичный, спрайты аналогичные, но там работает, а тут нет.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. Хотя бы гипотезы. Может кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обнаружил проблему. Я мало дал информации по вопросу, потому что сам не знал, в чем может быть проблема и какую информацию нужно давать.

Оказалось неисправность была в самом `svg`. Нужно всего лишь выставить `width` и `height` у `svg`, например:

Было:

```
// Не корректно отображается в explorer
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 663 106">
  ...
</svg>
```

Сделал:

```
// Корректно отображается в explorer
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="663" height="106" viewBox="0 0 663 106">
  ...
</svg>
```

Вуаля! Немного смещены (еще не поправлял), но зато масштаб правильный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]